# Ошибка при загрузки в виртуальной машине android studio (GPU Driver Issue)

Tags: android, android-studio, gpu

Установил андройстудио 3.0.1, сдк и тому подобные вещи, создал виртуальный девайс, однако, каждый раз, как загружаю приложение, высвечивается ошибка `"GPU Driver Issue".` Еще, в консоли `"Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\User\.android\avd\Pixel_API_22.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied".` Ошибку консоли пытался решить отключением того файла на чтение, но ситуация не исправилась. Подскажите, как решить проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали студию от админа запустить?

Comment: Да, пробовал, также черный экран, с надписью android, приложение не грузится @РусланЯгупов

Comment: Также ошибка "Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open ...\pstore.bin: Permission denied", но если менять с режима "только чтение", тот файл сам обратный ставит то значение @РусланЯгупов

Comment: Попробуйте обновить драйвера на видеокарту

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте **удалить виртуальную машину**, и *создать заново*. Мне помогает при такой же ошибки. Удачи